# Локализовать картинку и заменить Е на Ё на странице справки о рекламе

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, ё

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads

Заменить на эту, к примеру:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заодно:

1. **войдете** → **войдёте**.
2. **насчет** → **насчёт**.

Comment: Шрифт какой-то странный на картинке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большое спасибо за снимок! Обновил публикацию.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80